# How to show input when selected options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to detect the index of selected options and check if it == `Analog`.

then show new input box.

**code for my operation:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="setting.port" ng- options="item.name group by item.type for item in filteredPorts(index) track by item.name" ng-change="updateAll(index)">
  <option value="">-- Module Port --</option>
</select>
<div ng-if="setting.port.type == Analog">
<input type="text" name="min" placeholder="Min value" ng-model="setting.min">
<input type="text" name="max" placeholder="Max value" ng-model="setting.max">
</div>
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/TvvTlAp1IJqELCuMjcZI?p=preview) a link to my code:

Comment: where is `Analog` defined?

Comment: Analog must be enclosed in quotes: <div ng-if="setting.port.type == 'Analog'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-if="setting.port.type == 'Analog'">
```

You may now proceed to kick yourself :P

Comment: Oop!! Thanks @HankScorpio, my eye maybe blind :(.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes around Analog to your line with div ng-if.